# how to handle in cypress "Checking your browser before accessing app.hubspot.com"

Tags: automation, cypress

When I run the following cypress script:

```
describe('Handle Service Unavailable and Uncaught Exception', ()=>{
it('handle the hubspot login test', ()=>{
    cy.visit('https://app.hubspot.com/login', { failOnStatusCode: false})
    cy.wait(5000)
    cy.get('#username').should('be.visible').type('xxxx@gmail.com')
    cy.get('#password').should('be.visible').type('xxxxx@g123')
    cy.get('#loginBtn').should('be.visible').click()

})
```

})

https://app.hubspot.com/login URL stuck at message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZoBR.png)

Hence not able to get the #username field and type the username details.

Comment: What browser are you using with Cypress to access the URL? And why do you want to do the HubSpot login via the UI? In general, it is often better to perform the login via request instead of checking a third-party UI form that might change, which would cause your tests to break.

Comment: I am using chrome 97 version

Answer (score 1):

You cant directly got to login page and try below.

```
it('handle the hubspot login test', ()=>{
    cy.visit('https://www.hubspot.com/');
    cy.get('.homepage-nav-login').click();
})
```

This worked for me.

[image]

Comment: @Prasad It will ask for cookies permission you can click on allow cookies

Comment: not it did not help me. Thank you

Comment: Can you explain me , Whats ur issue in detail? Same url i visited and worked for me